# Goal seek in VBA error "reference isn't valid"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the `GoalSeek` function in Excel's VBA.

It says "reference isn't valid", and I know that it refers to the reference `r` and `c`, cause if I put in numbers instead, it runs smooth.
However, if I split up the code, I can see that `r`=68 and `c`=7, which is the correct numbers. So it's when the reference is put into the `Cells` reference in the goal seek function it does not work and I get the error "reference isn't valid".
Are there some kind of `Dim` or `Set` that I am missing?

```vb
Sub MacroTest1()
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    
    r = Range("LeverageRatioPeriod").Row
    c = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("MaxAcquisitionYear"), Range("YearRange"), 0)
    
    Cells(r, c).GoalSeek Goal:=4, ChangingCell:=Range("MaxEV")
```

Comment: What does `Cells(r, c)` contain?

Comment: I did some tests and got the error (only) when `ChangingCell` was set to a Range with more than one cell. What is `Range("MaxEV")`?

Comment: @GSerg I want to reference to a cell in the active worksheet that is in row 68 and column 7 which is "r" and "c" that I have set in the previous two rows

Comment: @FunThomas Range "MaxEV" is a named range that includes only a single cell. 
So the problem lies in the cells(r,c) reference. But I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: That is fine, however, what does `Cells(r, c)` contain?

Comment: Ah, another possible cause for the error: The destination cell needs to have a formula. So GSerg's question is valid: What is the content of `Cells(r, c)`?

Comment: @FunThomas your comment just saved me lots of time! I have found that for GoalSeek to work correctly from VBA, the "ChangingCell" should be a value, and not a formula. Maybe this information can help people with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what is entered in the cell Range("MaxEV"). If there is a formula there, please replace it with a simple value. In my case, this resolved a similar issue, and GoalSeek finally returned a value.